# Load Balancer marks instances as unhealthy even though no health checks are enabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I am trying to setup a TCP load balancer for ports 80 & 443. I have created an instance group and I can curl the instances and verify they are running.  However the load balancer states the instances are unhealthy. I originally tried setting them up with health checks, but removed the health checks just to get the load balancer working. Even with the health checks removed, the load balancer says the nodes are unhealthy.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsFZG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using Docker & Mesos, and changing the networking mode from Bridge to Host seems to have fixed the issue.